# Need Recommendation For Wireless Keyboard + Trackpad

Tags: wireless, keyboards, touchpad

I've got a Logitech K400+ wireless keyboard.

It leaves much to be desired, as far as I'm concerned:

1. keys too close together for reliable 'touch' typing
2. insufficient travel on the keys - too spongy
3. up/down cursors are too small - too easy to hit SHIFT instead of UP or UP instead of DOWN
4. trackpad very imprecise - too much over/under-shoot when making adjustments to things (faders/knobs/etc.) and scrolling frequently results in jumps (halfway down the page instead of three lines)

I've read any number of reviews of various keyboards on Amazon and elsewhere and, whatever the keyboard, if it has a trackpad, just about all of them reach pretty much the same conclusion: the trackpad is unsuited to precise pointer manipulation.

So, I've had an idea: what if I affix a good keyboard to a 'tray' along with a dedicated trackpad - can I get a better result that way?

Can anyone make any recommendations, therefore?

They're for use in my studio and will be spending most of their time on my lap, not set down beside me, and will, furthermore, be affixed to some plastic/wood/whatever and take on extra weight as a result, so

The keyboard needs to

1. not be *too* big and heavy to start with
2. be wireless (wifi dongle rather than Bluetooth)
3. ideally, have a numeric keypad - but I'll live without this, if necessary
4. have better key travel than the K400+
5. have more space between the keys than the K400+, without becoming excessively long - 40cm/14" seems reasonable, but I don't want the whole thing (keyboard+trackpad) to exceed 50cm/20"
6. use AA/AAA batteries rather than be rechargeable

The trackpad needs to be

1. wireless (wifi dongle rather than Bluetooth)
2. precise but not a (Microsoft) 'Precision' pad - I don't use (or care about) gesture control, I'm just sick of being able to move faders and knobs to -0.1/+0.1 or -4.3/-4.5 but never exactly 0.0 or -4.4 (you get the idea).

Comment: What's your budget? Would you prefer a wireless mouse instead of a trackpad, space (and budget) allowing?

Comment: No space for a mouse or even a trackball - hence the need for a wireless trackpad

Budget isn't an enormous issue, but I'd like to keep it within rough;y the £200 - £300 range for both, if I can